# MySQL DB with multiple numbers show as rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a rather complicated question (for me at least)

I have the following table structure

```
| id | roomtype | roomno | feature
| 1  |    STDK  |   11   |  BT
| 2  |    STDK  |   11   |  AE
| 3  |    STDK  |   22   |  SMK
| 4  |    STDK  |   22   |  BT
| 5  |    STDT  |   33   |  NONSMK
```

and I want to have an output like this

```
Type: STDK - RoomNo: 11 - Features: BT, AE
Type: STDK - RoomNo: 22 - Features: SMK, BT
Type: STDT - RoomNo: 33 - Features: NONSMK
```

It's probably not that complicated but I can't get it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This shows the result you're looking for... But I don't like the idea of formatting the result in the query!

```
select
    concat("Type: ", roomtype,
    " - RoomNo: ", roomno,
    " - Features: ", group_concat(feature order by feature separator ', '))
    as result
from t1
group by roomtype, roomno
```

Here is a working [example](http://sqlize.com/6aSnVs04M7)

Comment: +1 for not liking the idea of all that formatting in SQL and for teaching me about sqlize.com

Comment: Thanks ^.^ There are some other useful links in my profile (I'm lazy, I don't even bookmark them) :P

Comment: I have a couple jsfiddle.net boiler plate setups in mine.

Comment: Great thanks, that's what I was looking for, although I think I'll make some changes, since I don't like the idea of SQL formatting as well. GROUP_CONCAT was what I was looking for, the rest will be done by the php... cheers and thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use MySQL's [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select roomtype, roomno, group_concat(feature order by feature separator ', ')
from your_table
group by roomtype, roomno
order by roomno
```

Producing your fully formatted output from that is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     roomtype AS Type, 
     roomno AS RoomNo, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(feature ORDER BY feature SEPARATOR ', ') AS Features
FROM 
    tableName
GROUP BY roomtype, roomno
ORDER BY roomno
```